# Plotly Choropleth Map not plotting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-visualization, choropleth

I'm trying to visualize some data with Plotly in Jupyter notebook but the choropleth map is not showing up, as you can see from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYMpG.png).

The data set I'm working on is from https://csbh-dashboard.mckinsey.com/#/data-insights?chart=SP&geo=County&lob=All&metric1=covid_case_count&metric2=covid_death_count_per_100k_pop&tab=Map

I've tried following a few past submissions from here but I have not made any progress. I would appreciate any help in this direction, Thank you.Here is the code so far

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected = True)

df = pd.read_csv('State-level-data_31_07_2021.csv')
df.head()

data = dict(type='choropleth',
        locations = df['State'],
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        colorscale = 'Greens',
        text = df['State Code'],
        z = df['Cases of COVID-19'],
        colorbar = {'title':"Cases of COVID-19"}
        )
       
layout = dict(title = 'Cases of COVID-19 in USA Map',
          geo = dict(scope='usa')
         )

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout = layout)
iplot(choromap)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not use the data you presented because it requires registration. Instead, I modified your code based on the example in the official [reference](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-maps-with-gochoropleth). I'm not sure what the data format is, but it must be a state code to be specified in the Locations. The code style has been changed to the format used in the official reference. In addition, this is not the cause of the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

df.head()
```

|  | code | state | category | total exports | beef | pork | poultry | dairy | fruits fresh | fruits proc | total fruits | veggies fresh | veggies proc | total veggies | corn | wheat | cotton |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AL | Alabama | state | 1390.63 | 34.4 | 10.6 | 481 | 4.06 | 8 | 17.1 | 25.11 | 5.5 | 8.9 | 14.33 | 34.9 | 70 | 317.61 |
| 1 | AK | Alaska | state | 13.31 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0 | 0.19 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.6 | 1 | 1.56 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | AZ | Arizona | state | 1463.17 | 71.3 | 17.9 | 0 | 105.48 | 19.3 | 41 | 60.27 | 147.5 | 239.4 | 386.91 | 7.3 | 48.7 | 423.95 |
| 3 | AR | Arkansas | state | 3586.02 | 53.2 | 29.4 | 562.9 | 3.53 | 2.2 | 4.7 | 6.88 | 4.4 | 7.1 | 11.45 | 69.5 | 114.5 | 665.44 |
| 4 | CA | California | state | 16472.9 | 228.7 | 11.1 | 225.4 | 929.95 | 2791.8 | 5944.6 | 8736.4 | 803.2 | 1303.5 | 2106.79 | 34.6 | 249.3 | 1064.95 |

```
fig = go.Figure(data = go.Choropleth(
    locations = df['code'],
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    colorscale = 'Greens',
    text = df['code'],
    z = df['total exports'].astype(float),
    colorbar_title = "Total Exports"
))
       
fig.update_layout(
    title_text = 'Total Exports in USA Map',
    geo_scope = 'usa'
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There are four locator modes: ISO-3, USA-states, country names, and geojison-id, where USA-states is an abbreviation for a state. If this answer is helpful to you, please click the check mark to accept this answer.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. however, I did not quite understand your last sentence. If I'm trying to visualise multiple variables in a single plot say  beef, pork, poultry etc per your dataset what's the code for that? thank you

Comment: The official reference is written in the form of a graph definition, followed by the definition of graph elements and the addition of layout definitions, so I followed that. This is not the main topic, so you can ignore it. The data is sample data, and it is not possible to visualize multiple items.